# How do you use Win32DiskImager to create a ubuntu installation media from ubuntu 20.04 .iso file?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb

I'm trying to create an installation USB of Ubuntu 20.04, so I can duel boot with Windows 10.

I'm following to create one: https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/installation-media#windows
It says to use Win32DiskImager to create the USB. But the only download of ubuntu on the site is a .iso file, but Win32DiskImager only accepts .img files. But I can't find a .img file anywhere of ubuntu 20.04.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you!

Edit: I have been changing it to all files and when I change it to all files it only shows .exe files.

Comment: why not use rufus to do the job https://rufus-usb.en.uptodown.com/windows

Comment: I tried rufus too just now and it also isn't showing the file even when doing all files and only shows the .exe files that are in my downloads folder. Idk what is up. @trondhansen

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! I have to login with admin to run rufus or Win32DiskImager, but I had installed the ISO file on my personal user account!